# How to group by hour in Google Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

My Google Bigquery table have date and time column. New data are posted in table every 10 minutes, so date field would have e.g. "2018-10-26" and time field "19:05:00". Next record would be like "2018-10-26" and "19:15:00" for date and time field. How to aggregate data for each day by one hour (24 records per day)?

SQL request is sent from Google Sheets using Apps Script. Here is part of google bigquery.gs script: ([complete script in GitHub](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-samples/blob/master/advanced/bigquery.gs))

```
...
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var sql = 'SELECT  date, time, SUM(col1) AS Col1, SUM(col2) AS Col2 GROUP BY 
time, date ORDER BY time ASC';

var queryResults; 

// Inserts a Query Job
try {
var queryRequest = BigQuery.newQueryRequest();
queryRequest.setQuery(sql).setTimeoutMs(100000);
queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(queryRequest, projectNumber);
}
....
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT date, TIME_TRUNC(time, HOUR) hour, SUM(col1) AS Col1, SUM(col2) AS Col2 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY date, hour 
ORDER BY date, hour
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data in your question:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE "2018-10-26" date, TIME "19:05:00" time, 1 col1, 2 col2 UNION ALL
  SELECT "2018-10-26", "19:15:00", 3, 4
) 
SELECT date, TIME_TRUNC(time, HOUR) hour, SUM(col1) AS Col1, SUM(col2) AS Col2 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY date, hour 
ORDER BY date, hour
```

with result

```
Row date        hour        Col1    Col2     
1   2018-10-26  19:00:00    4       6
```

Comment: Time_Trunc function genereting error : GoogleJsonResponseException: 1.25 - 1.36: Unrecognized function time_trunc

Comment: You didn't include the `#standardSQL` part, which would enable standard SQL as the dialect.

Comment: @Elliott Brossard , I have included it and my App Script looks like this: var sql = `'#standardSQL SELECT  date, TIME_TRUNC(time, HOUR) as hour, SUM(... ` , but now I have error: **GoogleJsonResponseException: 1.1118 - 1.1118: No query found.** Should I include it somehow different way?

Comment: You have to put a newline between the prefix and the query itself. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#sql-prefix

Comment: Ok, now it works, thank You for hint! I set it in this way - `queryRequest.useLegacySql = false;`
Now my script looks like this:
    `// Inserts a Query Job
      try {
    var queryRequest = BigQuery.newQueryRequest();
    queryRequest.useLegacySql = false;
    queryRequest.setQuery(sql).setTimeoutMs(100000);
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(queryRequest, projectNumber);
    }...`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extract()`:

```
SELECT date, extract(hour from time) as hh,
       SUM(col1) AS Col1, SUM(col2) AS Col2
FROM ?
GROUP BY date, hh 
ORDER BY date, hh ASC;
```

Why would you be storing datetime values in two separate columns, rather than a single `datetime` or `timestamp` column?

Comment: extract() is generating error:
    GoogleJsonResponseException: 1.22 - 1.27: Unrecognized function extract

Yes, It is possible to store in one single column, but does it help for this problem?

Comment: @Intars_K . . . `extract()` works fine for me:  `select extract(hour from cast('10:00:00' as time))`.

Comment: I'm using this SQL query in bigquery.gs script and now it loks like this: `var sql = 'SELECT  date, extract(HOUR FROM time) as hour, SUM(col1...`. And this is generating **GoogleJsonResponseException: Encountered " "FROM" "FROM "" at line 1, column 28. Was expecting: ")" ...** Probably this approach will not work for Google Sheets using Apps Script

Comment: You need to enable standard SQL.

Comment: @Elliott Brossard, including this like: `var sql = '#standardSQL SELECT  date, extract(hour from cast("10:10:10" as time)),` is generating error: **GoogleJsonResponseException: 1.1134 - 1.1134: No query found.**